# Maven querydsl configuration doesn't work

Tags: spring, maven, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

this is the first time that i work with Spring-Data-jpa and Querydsl.

I'm trying to configure the automatic genenation of the DataModel.

I carried out the followed steps:

i added the following dependencies at the pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

and then i added the following plugin

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-apt-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

but i get always the same error in the pom.xml:

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.mysema.maven:maven-apt-plugin:1.0.2:process (execution: default, phase: generate-sources)

and the folder target/generated-sources/java is not generated and filled.
Where I worng?

Comment: This sounds like an Eclipse m2e issue. Could you clarify this in your question? Does it work in the Maven build?

Comment: As Timo said, this is an Eclipse issue. See my answer in this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29234546/1546146

Answer (score 1):

use this plugin it works version 1.1.1

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Specifies the directory in which the query types are generated -->
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                            <!-- States that the APT code generator should look for JPA annotations -->
                                <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies:

```
<!-- Query DSL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Build Plugin:

```
<plugin>
                        <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1.3</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>process</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                                    <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following if you are using m2e

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
                <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.7</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
                <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
                <classifier>apt</classifier>
                <version>3.6.7</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Installed JREs: jre --> jdk resolve this problem